# Issues comparing two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am starting with a string of MAC addresses and a list of MAC addresses:

```
s3_mac_string = "[['50:9a:4c:17:b4:f5', '54:13:79:70:6b:97', '54:13:79:70:6b:98', '56:13:79:70:6b:97', '66:13:79:70:6b:97'], ['c8:34:8e:72:3f:89', 'c8:34:8e:72:3f:8a', 'ca:34:8e:72:3f:89'], ['54:ee:75:b7:9f:a4', 'f0:d5:bf:bf:65:ee', 'f0:d5:bf:bf:65:ef', 'f2:d5:bf:bf:65:ee']]"
huntress_unseen_mac = [['80:86:f2:da:dd:ce', '80:86:f2:da:dd:cf', '80:86:f2:da:dd:d2', '82:86:f2:da:dd:ce', 'ec:f4:bb:40:25:be'], ['10:60:4b:73:39:db'], ['a4:bb:6d:3f:ed:10'], ['a4:bb:6d:3e:7b:e1'], ['d0:3c:1f:77:84:b3', 'd0:3c:1f:77:84:b4', 'f0:d5:bf:bf:65:ee', 'd0:3c:1f:77:84:b7']]
```

I am then converting `string1` to a list with this function:

```
def Convert(string):
    string = string.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace('"', "").replace("'", "")
    li = list(string.split(","))
    return li
```

My main():

```
def main():
    s3_mac_string = get_mac_addresses_from_s3()
    huntress_unseen_mac = get_unseen_mac_huntress()
    s3_mac_list = Convert(s3_mac_string)

    huntress_unseen_mac_lower = [
        str(huntress_unseen_mac).lower().strip()
        for huntress_unseen_mac in huntress_unseen_mac
    ]

    s3_mac_list_lower = [str(s3_mac).lower().strip() for s3_mac in s3_mac_list]

    common_macs = []
    for mac in huntress_unseen_mac_lower:
        if mac in s3_mac_list_lower:
            common_macs.append(mac)

    print(f"Common MACs: {common_macs}")
```

The printing of the common macs is just printing an empty list eventhough there are commonalities between the lists. As a troubleshooting step I appended the huntress_unseen_mac_lower with `huntress_unseen_mac_lower.appent("<MAC THAT IS IN S3_MAC_LIST")`

I also tried using set intersection initially and that didn't work either.

```
    huntress_unseen_mac_lower = [
        str(huntress_unseen_mac).lower() for huntress_unseen_mac in huntress_unseen_mac
    ]
    s3_mac_list_lower = [str(s3_mac).lower() for s3_mac in s3_mac_list]

    common_macs = set(huntress_unseen_mac_lower).intersection(s3_mac_list_lower)

    print(f"Common Macs: {list(common_macs)}")
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: The value assigned to huntress_unseen_mac in syntactically flawed

Comment: @Codist I think I fixed it. Sorry I pulled that snippet from an output of about 600 MAC addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a list of lists from s3_mac_string using ast.literal_eval.

From that, build a set from all the sub-elements.

Build another set from huntress_unseen_mac (which is already a list of lists).

Print the intersection of the two sets.

```
from ast import literal_eval

def as_set(_list: list[list[str]]) -> set:
    s = set()
    s.update(*_list)
    return s

s3_mac_string = "[['50:9a:4c:17:b4:f5', '54:13:79:70:6b:97', '54:13:79:70:6b:98', '56:13:79:70:6b:97', '66:13:79:70:6b:97'], ['c8:34:8e:72:3f:89', 'c8:34:8e:72:3f:8a', 'ca:34:8e:72:3f:89'], ['54:ee:75:b7:9f:a4', 'f0:d5:bf:bf:65:ee', 'f0:d5:bf:bf:65:ef', 'f2:d5:bf:bf:65:ee']]"
huntress_unseen_mac = [['80:86:f2:da:dd:ce', '80:86:f2:da:dd:cf', '80:86:f2:da:dd:d2', '82:86:f2:da:dd:ce', 'ec:f4:bb:40:25:be'], ['10:60:4b:73:39:db'], ['a4:bb:6d:3f:ed:10'], ['a4:bb:6d:3e:7b:e1'], ['d0:3c:1f:77:84:b3', 'd0:3c:1f:77:84:b4', 'f0:d5:bf:bf:65:ee', 'd0:3c:1f:77:84:b7']]

s3_mac_set = as_set(literal_eval(s3_mac_string))
h_mac_set = as_set(huntress_unseen_mac)

print(s3_mac_set & h_mac_set)
```

**Output:**

```
{'f0:d5:bf:bf:65:ee'}
```

Answer (score 0):

huntress_unseen_mac is a list of lists, flatten it before doing any conversion to lower or comparison.

`huntress_unseen_mac = [item for sublist in huntress_unseen_mac for item in sublist]`

Output:
`Common MACs: ['f0:d5:bf:bf:65:ee']`

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I knew I was missing something small!

Answer (score 0):

Essentially in your for loop, the `huntress_unseen_mac_lower` contains a list of strings

```
<class 'list'> ["['80:86:f2:da:dd:ce', '80:86:f2:da:dd:cf', '80:86:f2:da:dd:d2', '82:86:f2:da:dd:ce', 'ec:f4:bb:40:25:be']", "['10:60:4b:73:39:db']", "['a4:bb:6d:3f:ed:10']", "['a4:bb:6d:3e:7b:e1']", "['d0:3c:1f:77:84:b3', 'd0:3c:1f:77:84:b4', 'f0:d5:bf:bf:65:ee', 'd0:3c:1f:77:84:b7']"]
```

So it is unable to find a MAC address inside the string of multiple mac addresses.

I think you don't need the `s3_mac_list_lower` at all.
So i updated your for loop into

```
common_macs = []
for mac in huntress_unseen_mac:
    for m in mac:
        if m in s3_mac_list_lower:
            common_macs.append(m)
```

which prints

```
Common MACs: ['f0:d5:bf:bf:65:ee']
```